# Install Sopcast in 64-bits

Tags: apt

I'm a new user of Ubuntu and I'm finding a lot of difficulties installing Sopcat

I used the following code:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ferramroberto/sopcast
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sopcast-player
```

After the last command, I had the following answer

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
sopcast-player : Depends: sp-auth (>= 3.0.1) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I googled the problem and I found out that I have to install the package sp-auth_3.2.6.1~lffl~natty~ppa_i386.deb on https://launchpad.net/~ferramroberto/+archive/sopcast/+build/2405344

But when I try to install it appears in my software center "wrong architechture 'i386' "

Any suggestions?

Comment: On the Ubuntu forums is the exact same issue being solved: [SOLVED Problem with installation of Sopcast](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2072852) Basically, you're running the `amd64` architecture, but trying to install the `i386` version.

Comment: That's the diagnoses

Comment: How can I fix it

Comment: Have you scrolled down that page? Message 6 is marked as the solution. That approach is not in your question, so I guess it's something you haven't tried yet.

Comment: Error page: This page does not exist

Comment: where can i find the package for the amd64?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem installing **Sopcast** at first, lots of tutorials in internet were just waste of time. The main problem was, the link was broken in Ubuntu forum and launchpad gives 404 error while clicking the page. I went to the `femroberto` page but there was no download link for 64bit package. There was a bug filed in launchpad about `sp-auth` installation, and no download link available for `amd64` architecture. So, what I did to install was:

- sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ferramroberto/sopcast (*To add the repository*)
- Downloaded the sp-auth package from this website http://www.n00bsonubuntu.net/content/how-to-install-sopcast-on-ubuntu-13-04/
- Installed the sp-auth package first using `gdebi package installer`. You can right click and use `ubuntu software centre` too.
- **From Terminal:** sudo apt-get update
- sudo apt-get install sopcast-player
- **Finally for Firefox to recognise the `sop://` link** (*Though not important for latest firefox*)

  - In Firefox address bar, type `about:config` and Enter the config
  - Search for `network.protocol-handler.expose-all` and try by changing the value to `true` or `false`. In my case it worked with `true`.

Now I am using sop-cast player

Comment: This won't work on Raring 13.04 upwards.

Comment: I am using Sopcast in 13.10 with same method. Please explain how it doesn't work? what problem you faced? what steps you did?

Comment: You sure, I just tried `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ferramroberto/sopcast` and the repository didn't have the raring nor saucy packages. This can verified [here](https://launchpad.net/~ferramroberto/+archive/sopcast/+packages) where it says "This PPA currently publishes packages for Quantal, Precise, Oneiric, Natty, Maverick, Lucid, Karmic, Jaunty, and Hardy." If you can, it's maybe because yours is an upgraded system.

Comment: Works on Linux Mint 17.  Thanks!

Comment: btw I installed sopcast player from Google Code by following Step 2 here instead of your instructions above:  http://www.sysads.co.uk/2014/06/install-sopcast-player-0-8-5-ubuntu-14-04/ .  For some reason, sopcast-player wouldn't install via apt-get (ppa, repo issue?).

Answer (score 3):

Sadly, the PPA won't work for Raring (13.04) and up. You need the command line version instead. For 64-bits you need to install first the `libstdc++5:i386` package:

```
sudo apt-get install libstdc++5:i386
```

Download the binary and untar it:

```
wget http://download.easetuner.com/download/sp-auth.tgz
tar xf sp-auth.tgz
cd sp-auth
```

Now you can run it just using:

```
> ./sp-sc-auth    
SC Version: 3.2.6  Build time: 2009-11-09 15:09
Usage:
./sp-sc [-TpI] [-b ipaddr] [-u username:password] [-n out:total] <sop://url> <localport> <playerport>
```

If you get a message like this, you didn't installed the libstdc++5:i386 library at the start:

```
./sp-sc-auth
zsh: no such file or directory: ./sp-sc-auth
```

To use the program I recommend the use of [this helper](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~chickamade/sopcast.sh/master/view/head:/sopcast).

A simple example of `sp-sc-auth` command line (see `README` file from inside of `sp-auth` directory):

```
./sp-sc-auth sop://broker.sopcast.com:3912/148248 3908 8908  > /dev/null &
```

will start to transfer National Geographic channel, and you can play it on the port 8908 with VLC or mplayer for example by open the url:

```
http://localhost:8908/tv.asf
```

Comment: @RaduRădeanu the syntax is not like that http://paste.ubuntu.com/7181878/. [Use this helper instead](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~chickamade/sopcast.sh/master/view/head:/sopcast), the error you are seeing is because the program doesn't gracefully error out when it fails.

Comment: Yes, I get it after I read the ...`README` file from `sp-auth` directory :D. Thanks, it works great in 14.04, 64 bit.